# How to deal with a popular question whose answers are beyond my understanding?

Tags: discussion

I had asked [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9155/variant-of-lion-and-100-zebras) question, and it gathered a lot of answers, including some faulty and some highly technical answers. From what I can understand, no one has actually posted a sufficient proof yet. However, as I am unable to understand some of the logic used in the answers (maybe it's faulty), I can't say for sure.

Please let me know if I should accept one of the answers, or else I would like to put a bounty on the Q.

P.S. Please don't tell me why *your* answer is right.

Answer (score 2):

When faced with a situation like this, your best bet is to find a friend who is a mathematician and ask for help learning the things that those answers are positing.

Most likely they'll be able to come up with a better way to explain the answer anyway, but I digress.

Odds are, the answers posted aren't quite up to snuff and could use some work to make them user-friendly. I think I agree that the answers posted there don't seem to be written in a way that's easy to parse. So that's not your fault.

If you don't have a math-friend, no fret! We have a few people here who are experts. You did the right thing by posting in the meta board.